# GAE: Is it possibility to execute external program from within gae queue?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to handle user data in [queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) with some external program. Is it possible? First of all i must upload and install this software somewhere... Then run it within queue environment. How i can do it?
If it is impossible on GAE, can you advice me another cloud platform with ability to run programs with queue interface, like for example [OGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Grid_Engine) or something else..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need both access to GAE Datastore (to load user data) and ability to execute external program (to analyse it)?

At the moment GAE does not allow executing arbitrary programs, so answer is no.

However, there is an upcoming feature called [VM-based backends](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/gRZNqlQPKys/BbOHxcgYt2IJ), which will allow you to start [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine/) instances (with ability to run arbitrary programs) and have those instances access the GAE Datastore. This is at the moment a trusted-tester feature (a limited beta), I guess it'll be available in a couple of months.